# Does ROS move base require the base controller to give the position information?

Tags: navigation, move-base, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm reading [Publishing Odometry Information over ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom). Does ROS move base require the base controller to give the position information on the Map? Is it mandatory ?

I thought move base is able to figure out the pose information from the linear velocity and radian  velocity.  Would [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) help if I don't want to do the computation?

I'm using a four wheel car, it's my own make.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201846/does-ros-move-base-require-the-base-controller-to-give-the-position-information?/) by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the map, no. However, navigation requires knowing where the robot is relative to some odometry frame, and the the local planner requires the odometry information to figure out the current speed.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0